# pre commit hook - update committed file

Tags: windows, git, phpstorm

I'm trying to automatically add my database to version control with a pre-commit hook.

I have made a script that creates an SQL file containing the database structure in the project root, and the sql file is in the commit list (in PhpStorm) before the hook runs.

My problem is that the old version of the file is the one that ends up getting committed instead of the current one. I thought about using a post commit hook to then amend the changes, but I fear I might end up in an infinite loop of commits.

Comment: It's usually a bad idea to commit database files in the first place. That said, newer versions of Git re-scan the index after the pre-commit hook runs, in case the hook modified the index (e.g., `git add`-ed something). Older versions of Git don't, which means the pre-commit hook must add and commit itself, then abort the "outer" commit. This makes it possible either way, but quite ugly when using older Git versions.

Comment: @torek so I just need to `git add` the modified file in the hook and make sure my git version is up to date?

Comment: Pretty much.  The current Git is 2.10 (see https://github.com/blog/2242-git-2-10-has-been-released) but 2.9.x or even 2.8.x are common now. I'm not sure when the rescan-after-hook went in.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it out tonight